# Alternating (interleaving?) two XQuery For loops

Tags: loops, xquery

If a=A,B,C and b=1,2,3 then in XQuery I can have consecutive loops like:

```
{for $x in a
return $x}

{for $y in b
return $y}
```

which would return **A,B,C,1,2,3**

Or I could have nested loops like:

```
{for $x in a
return $x
    for $y in b
    return $y}}
```

which would return **A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3** (or maybe the other way around, but you know what I mean).

However, what I need is to return **A,1,B,2,C,3**

I'm struggling to see a way to have two loops but alternate the results of them in my output. Any suggestions? I've searched for a solution, but I'm no XQuery expert and I'm not even sure I'm using the correct terminology.

Comment: Are sequences `a` and `b` guaranteed to be the same length? If so, you could iterate over one and use the position from that loop to get the value at the same position in the other sequence.

Answer (score 3):

In XQuery 3.0 there is the *higher-order* function [`fn:for-each-pair($seq1, $seq2, $f)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-for-each-pair) which applies a user-supplied function to the first, second etc. item of the two input sequences `$f($seq1[1], $seq2[1]), $f($seq1[2], $seq2[2]), ...` until one of the sequences is exhausted. For your use case you just want sequence concatenation:

```
fn:for-each-pair(('A', 'B', 'C'), (1, 2, 3), function($a, $b) { $a, $b })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the position of the iterator in the first sequence to get the value at the same position in the second sequence:

```
for $x at $pos in a
let $y := b[$pos]
return ($x, $y)
```